# how to take a variable number of arguments of any type and prints each one on a separate line in C?

Tags: c, generics, variadic-functions

I am trying to take a few inputs from the user and then pass them into a function which prints each one on the screen but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I feel that an array would be more appropriate here

Comment: @MohamadAliBaydoun Well it's an assignment and it asks you to make A function myPrinter which takes in a variable number of arguments of any type and prints each one a separate line.

Comment: Here's an [example](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Example.html) of a variadic function that might be helpful.

Comment: @MohamadAliBaydoun well in that example we specifically say the type of the argument ( va_arg (ap, int)) but in this one we don't know what type does it have and because of that I don't know how to print it on the screen knowing that it can be a string or a char we need two different print statements

Comment: @AliAgharazi: You don't need two different print statements. The printf function uses a format string as its first parameter to specify the types of the remaining function arguments. Why not do something similar with your variadic function?

Comment: for sure you have attempted something... is it possible you edit your question, including a minimum, complete and verifiable code?

Comment: You'll need some way to specify the parameter types you have... inside your variadic function, sooner or later you'll have to use `va_arg()` macro, and it needs to specify the parameter type you have.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best examples you have to be able to do that is the `printf(3)` family of functions.  On those, a first string allows you to specify the types and the order of the parameters that follow the format first parameter.

If you think you have some magical way to do it better, I'd like to know about.  Of course, there are other approaches, but not better than this.

The main problem is that the type information doesn't end in the executable.  At the end, what you have is a bunch of machine instructions, that don't know about the `struct invoice` or `struct user` types.